# Div 100% page height, no vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This may seem trivial but I cannot seem to get this right.

I'm looking to create a border around my webpage, like these guys have done http://www.codeandpepper.com/

But I can't seem to get the border at 100% height of the screen without a vertical scroll. I would hope to still see the mitre joint at the base.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I've got so far..

```
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.frame.rightFrame {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-right: 45px solid red;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gavinfriel/knq4L3xf/2/

Comment: I think you all you needed was to add `left:0px; bottom: 0px` as well? Updated: https://jsfiddle.net/knq4L3xf/3/ Remove the `left` if you want it on the right side

Comment: God bless you sir. I did say it was trivial. Many thanks!!

Comment: I'll write it as answer in case you want to refer to it again, mark it if you want to or not

Comment: I'll also leave this here: https://jsfiddle.net/knq4L3xf/6/ The key is `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `bottom:0px` to rightframe:

```
.frame.rightFrame {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-right: 45px solid red;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: auto;
}
```

updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/knq4L3xf/5/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are using `height: auto`, which takes the default of the height of the content.

In order for the frame to take 100% of the height of the page, you're looking for `100vh`:

```
.frame.rightFrame {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

`vh` is short for 'viewport height'. I've created an updated fiddle showcasing this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/cqo218u5/) (though note that on JSFiddle you might be a little confused by the fact that it also will take into consideration the height of the CSS section).

```css
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.frame.rightFrame {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-right: 45px solid red;
  border-top: 45px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 45px solid transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame rightFrame"></div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi Obsidian, I've tried this to no avail. As you'll notice, your fiddle still scrolls vertically. The border doesn't fit on the page. Thanks for your input all the same

Comment: As I say, `100vh` calculates the height of the **viewport**. It won't work on JSFiddle because the section is split into four different areas, and it's also trying to display the height of the section above it (the CSS). It will work on your own site :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cqo218u5/2/ It works perfectly fine on jsfiddle, since it uses a frame to display the result. 100vh in a frame is the height of the frame, not the window.

Answer (score 1):

You can try jquery: 
`$("div").height($(window).height()-90);`

https://jsfiddle.net/8c2p70g9/

Answer (score 0):

add bottom zero

```
.frame.rightFrame {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  border-right: 45px solid red;
  border-top: 100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
  width: 10px;
  height: auto;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/knq4L3xf/7/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more readable version which uses `box-sizing:border-box` to make sure you can use 100% without overflowing.

For those who didn't look at the original website, note that the border is in 4 separate segments for hovering.

We're essentially making the whole border transparent then changing the color of specific segments. Overall that reduces the amount of CSS required, and makes it easier to follow too.

[Here it is as a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knq4L3xf/5/)

The commented CSS:

```
/*
    Dump the margin and make both html and body 100% high
    (as well as a dark-ish background color)
*/
html,body{
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
    background:#363b46;
}

/*
    Each frame element will be 45px and uses box-sizing.
    That'll make sure the size of the border itself doesn't cause it to overflow, 
    and 100% 'just works'.
    We'll also clear the width so we don't end up with them defaulting to width:auto
    and position them so they can get placed in specific locations.
*/

.frames{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    border:45px solid transparent;
    width:0;
    position:absolute;
}

/*
    Styling specific borders so they end up where they need to be
*/
.frameLeft{
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    border-left-color:#131c30;
}

.frameTop{
    width:100%;
    border-top-color:#131c30;
}

.frameRight{
    right:0;
    height:100%;
    border-right-color:#131c30;
}

.frameBottom{
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    border-bottom-color:#131c30;
}

/*
    The hover selectors - these changes specific borders
*/
.frameTop:hover{
    border-top-color:#7b9eeb;
}

.frameRight:hover{
    border-right-color:#7b9eeb;
}

.frameBottom:hover{
    border-bottom-color:#7b9eeb;
}

.frameLeft:hover{
    border-left-color:#7b9eeb;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<!-- The four frame parts -->
<div class='frames frameTop'></div>
<div class='frames frameLeft'></div>
<div class='frames frameBottom'></div>
<div class='frames frameRight'></div>
```